# Android build time increased from 8 secs to 90 secs without change

Tags: android

I finished more than 30 builds with my android project about 8 secs build time with Android Studio 3.0.1 and suddenly this build time increased to about 90 sec. No detected changes. I can't have any idea why?

How can I decrease the build time?

---------- addition ---------
About several days after 90sec build time the build time decreased back to 3sec again. I'm confused. :(((
[image]

Comment: May be your PC went slow for some reason. That could be a possibility.

Comment: It's hard to believe that you're re-building your app if you haven't changed anything. If you add a library or more code, the number of files in your project increases (obviously) and it takes more time for AS to build. As suggested you can try to use Instant Run to reduce the build time. Sometimes cleaning Android Studio cache can help too.

Comment: So... to feb 14 was the built time about 3 secs after 90 secs and today (and I can't modify anything (only replace a RAW source file ALT.OBJ a new one) and now the build time 3sec again :(( I'm confused.

Comment: I got it. If no Network, the build time about 4 secs, if has network but no internet the build time about 90 secs. With internet the build about 5 secs. :)

Answer (score 1):

The app normally takes more than 8 seconds to build. In Android studio 3.1 there is a feature called instant run that builds only the changes from last build. When you had to wait 90 seconds, Android studio must likely rebuilded the whole app.

[image: Android studio instant run feature]
If you want android studio to not rebuild the whole app, only the changes. However, this only works if your app is currently running on an emulator or connected device.

Comment: I used the "play" button only ( 3secs vs 90secs )

Comment: Maybe Android studio does not rebuild the entire app even though you do not use instant run.

Answer (score 0):

If network present but not reached the internet the build time increased to 90secs. If no net or internet reachable then the build time about 5 secs.